# How to include a piece of java code inside a html tag in play framework template?

Tags: java, html, playframework-1.x

I know I can use expression in play framework template like this.

`<h1>Client ${client.name}</h1>`

What to do if I need to include  ${client.name} in html tag?

For example,
     `<h1 id=${client.name}>Client ${client.name}</h1>`

However, this way doesn't works.

Comment: Have a look at [JavaScript entities](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/entity2.shtml#.UkEAkYZi1fQ)

Comment: I find Play throws an exception when interpret this javascript entity. @mdesdev

Comment: Ok then, have you accomplished something with the link I gave you?

Comment: I read the link, it says "ONLY in Netscape 4 and below", but I use chrome and firefox. Does it means it will not work? @mdesdev

Comment: @Dong it also says, "modern IE browsers such as IE6". I would avoid that site.

Comment: I got the solution. This way works. <h1 id="${client.name}">${client.name}</h1>@mdesdev @Mr Lister, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

First replace that example because the id need a "" to use like this

```
<h1 id="${client.name}">Client ${client.name}</h1>
```

then to use java code in your template use the %{ java code here }% tags you can create variables and use it like  `%{ string mystring = "hello";}%` then in the template`<h2>${mystring}</h2>`.

here are one example from my real code:

```
%{String selected = ""; if (permisoseleccionado?.Permiso?.id == tp?.id){selected = "selected";}}%
```

this post is old but I thing that this will be usefull to other people.

see ya!